# Redirect if ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, error-handling

I have the next code to save:

```
        Transaction.create(:status => params[:st], :transaction_id => params[:tx], :purchased_at => Time.now).save!
```

But how can I redirect to main root page if this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error appears? Can I catch this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the way you catch every other error

```
begin
  Transaction.create!(:status => params[:st], :transaction_id => params[:tx], :purchased_at => Time.now)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But can I use rescue for i18n error, too? I try `rescue i18n::InvalidLocale redirect_to "/#{params[:locale]}"` but it doesn't helps me. Any suggestions?